# How to redirect Spark output to console?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera, hadoop-yarn

I am running spark jobs on a CHD cluster and all the logs are stored into a history server as text files. Is there a way to get those outputs to print on the console? All I see is

```
15/10/21 15:47:09 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1445455790310_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/10/21 15:47:10 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1445455790310_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/10/21 15:47:11 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1445455790310_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/10/21 15:47:12 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1445455790310_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/10/21 15:47:13 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1445455790310_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/10/21 15:47:14 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1445455790310_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/10/21 15:47:15 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1445455790310_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/10/21 15:47:16 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1445455790310_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/10/21 15:47:17 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1445455790310_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/10/21 15:47:18 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1445455790310_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/10/21 15:47:19 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1445455790310_0014 (state: RUNNING)
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark logging system works with [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/).

According to the official [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging), Spark provides a configuration file named `log4j.properties.template`, in which you can specify different logging properties. 
The file is under the folder `conf` in the main Spark directory.

In order to let Spark detect and use this configuration file, it is necessary to rename it and remove the `.template` out of it.

The default template looks something like the following:

```
# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet=ERROR
log4j.logger.parquet=ERROR

...
```

In this example, the default logging method is set to console. Although I have not tested it, you should be able to see the output out of the box with this example template.